# Update values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, replace

I would like to update fields in my dataframe  :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Name': 'Paul', 'Book': 'Plane', 'Cost': 22.50},
    {'Name': 'Jean', 'Book': 'Harry Potter', 'Cost': 2.50},
    {'Name': 'Jim', 'Book': 'Sponge bob', 'Cost': 5.00}
])

          Book  Cost  Name
0         Plane  22.5  Paul
1  Harry Potter   2.5  Jean
2    Sponge bob   5.0   Jim
```

Changing names with this string :

```
{"Paul": "Paula", "Jim": "Jimmy"}
```

to get this result :

```
          Book  Cost  Name
0         Plane  22.5  Paula
1  Harry Potter   2.5  Jean
2    Sponge bob   5.0   Jimmy
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `dictionary` `d`:

```
d = {"Paul": "Paula", "Jim": "Jimmy"}
df.Name = df.Name.replace(d)
print (df)
           Book  Cost   Name
0         Plane  22.5  Paula
1  Harry Potter   2.5   Jean
2    Sponge bob   5.0  Jimmy
```

Another solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) - `map` return `NaN` where not match, so need replace it by original values:

```
df.Name = df.Name.map(d).combine_first(df.Name)
print (df)
           Book  Cost   Name
0         Plane  22.5  Paula
1  Harry Potter   2.5   Jean
2    Sponge bob   5.0  Jimmy
```